# How do you trigger doors in the Descent 1 level "Titanium Falcon Military Depot"?

Tags: descent-1

Of the *Levels of the World* levels for the original Descent 1, one of the most obtuse is "Titanium Falcon Military Depot" (a.k.a. "T.F. Military Depot").  It starts out in a single room with some enemies.  The only door which doesn't need a key (aside from the doors to the player spawn locations and the exit door) is opened by flying over a spot next to the convex corner that's closest to the door in the room.

Behind that door is … another door.  It doesn't open when touched/shot.  Presumably, it is opened by flying over another trigger spot in the room, but I can't for the life of me find that spot.  Does anyone remember where it is?

Frustratingly, I'm pretty sure I figured it out when I first played this level in the 90s.  But that memory is gone.

The only mention I can find of this level at all is a ReadMe-ish document, found [here](http://www.pooterman.com/pooterman.com/ftp/descent/levels/titanium.txt), which contains:

```
Name of Mission: TiTANiUM FALCON MiLiTARY DEPOT

Description of mission: This level is a little tricky.....you must hit switches in order to open the      
doors to get the keys....but once you use your imagination the path will come to you. Use the       
clues i have provided.......they will help you out. What are behind the doors are either helpful 
or harmful (most cases both), so be careful!.....find the keys in succession and then advance 
your ship to the TiTANiUM FALCON to blow the reactor. *Intro as follows (optional):*

iNTRODUCTiON: THIS LEVEL IS A MILITARY DEPOT ON SATURN
COMPLETE WITH A HANGAR WHICH CONTAINS THE TiTANiUM FALCON, PTMC'S
NEWEST TOP SECRET ATTACK CRAFT, WHICH THE MECHS HAD BEEN STATIONED 
THERE TO GUARD, BUT ONCE THEY WERE INFECTED WITH THE MYSTERIOUS 
VIRUS, YOU MUST BE SENT IN BEFORE THE TITANIUM FALCON'S 
SUPERCOMPUTER BECOMES INFECTED....EVERY SECOND THE ViRUS SLOWLY 
EATS AWAY AT THE CIRCUITS.....UNTIL FINALLY IT WILL BECOME INFECTED AND
LAUNCH ITSELF.....PTMC'S HEADQUARTERS IS THE DESTINATION THAT IT WAS 
TRACKING, AND IF IT OPENS FIRE ON THE HQ, IT WILL CAUSE MASSIVE 
DESTRUCTION TO THE SPACE STATION.  
YOU MUST NOT LET THAT HAPPEN........DESTROY THE FALCON'S REACTOR AND 
VAPORIZE THE WHOLE DEPOT IMMEDIATLEY, BEFORE IT BECOMES INFECTED.
```

I like to think I'm pretty observant, but I haven't found any "clues" in the main room at all.  The trigger zone which opens the first door, I found by accident;  now, even knowing where it is, I still can find no clues that would have indicated its location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a ton of trial and error, I found the spot.  Fly around the other convex corner which is nearest to the convex corner where the first door's trigger is located.  Around that other corner is one of the many doors that requires the blue key;  approaching that locked door opens the inner of the two doors that leads to the blue key itself.

The yellow key is inside a blue wall panel in the first room.  It is triggered by passing through the blue door that leads to the second large room and entering the right side of the alcove that contains the energy replenishment field.

The red key is behind a regular door, the only one that cannot be directly opened after obtaining the blue and yellow keys.  It is triggered by flying through a very small area which is directly ahead of that door, a little ways from the opposite wall that is across the room from that door.